# Haskell Int to Float division

Tags: haskell

I want to find, if there is a same divisor between y,x and z,y following:

```
myFunc [x,y,z] = if y `div` x == z `div` y then True else False
```

But here I get True even if the divisor is not the same, let´s assume we have

```
x = 32
y = 64
z = 129
```

I suppose the problem is with `div`, which only makes int division. Is there any int to float divison in haskell that I could use to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

div is floor division. It returns floor of a/b. Change your function to:

```
myFunc [x,y,z] = (y `foo` x) == (z `foo` y) where foo a b = (fromIntegral a) / (fromIntegral b)
```

Comment: Then I receive `No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of /'` error.

Comment: oh, my ghci just inputed floats. How about now?

Comment: Would that help ? `((fromIntegral 129) / (fromIntegral 64)) :: Ratio Integer`

Comment: I think it should work already, but that might be good too